# How to check if app is updated or fresh install in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app in Windows phone 8. Can I determine through some App data if its a fresh install or an updated app on that device?

Comment: Of your own app? Why not just use local storage and a flat file as a database and increment it on first run or for each update... Or even use application version something like `if (appversion < this.appversion) {updateVersion; callSpecialCase; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string currentAppVer = string.Empty;
var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver() };
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("WMAppManifest.xml", xmlReaderSettings))
{
     xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("App");
     currentAppVer = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Version").Replace(".", "");
}

try
{
     if ((Convert.ToInt32(currentAppVer)) < (Convert.ToInt32(response.appVersion)))
     {
          MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
          marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = App.appContentIdentifier;
          marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
          marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
          Application.Current.Terminate();
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

Where `response.appVersion` is the Application Version that you can maintain in IsolatedStorageSettings OR in Database...